# How to get proper extension(.log) for a file generated by log4j configuration using DailyRollingFileAppender

Tags: logging, log4j

I have the log4j configuration, all properly set to get daily logs in separate files. I am using org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender. The problem I do have is with the extension. I get log_files with names, for example: abc.log.2013-1-23 and  abc.log.2013-1-24. but what I want is to get these files with names, as abc.2013-1-23.log and abc.2013-1-24.log. I should be able to see extension (.log) after the name-of-file-including-date! Any pointers? any help will be appreciated.